# Getting different errors in Userform Initialize suddenly

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am stuck in a really weird problem suddenly, and I could really use some help. My vba excel project has 4 main forms, and everything was working fine and suddenly 2 of the forms, userform_initialize suddenly started giving me weird errors

[image]

This is the full form code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Sheets("Inventory Record").Protect "Ramu@lt12", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
lastrow = Sheets("Inventory Record").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Me.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
For i = 2 To lastrow
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets("Inventory Record").Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i
End If
End Sub

Private Sub imgPDF_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Inventory Record PDF").Activate
Dim checklist As String
Dim filename As String
Dim fullfilename As String

checklist = Left(frm1.TextBox7.Value, 4) & "-" & Right(frm1.TextBox7.Value, 2)
MkDir (checklist)
filename = "Inventory Record " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".pdf"
fullfilename = "G:\BusUnits\PH\Sample management\" & checklist & "\" & filename


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=fullfilename, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1
    
Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

End Sub


Private Sub imgEdit_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to Edit the Entry?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    frmEdit1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub imgReset_Click()

Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to Reset the Form?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Call Reset1

End Sub

Private Sub imgSave_Click()

Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to save the Data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory Record")
Dim newDate As Date
newDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, DTPicker3.Value)
'find first row in database
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ws.Protect Password:="Ramu@lt12", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
With ws
.Range("A" & iRow) = TextBox1.Value
.Range("B" & iRow) = TextBox2.Value
.Range("C" & iRow) = TextBox3.Value
.Range("D" & iRow) = ComboBox2.Value
.Range("E" & iRow) = ComboBox3.Value
.Range("F" & iRow) = TextBox6.Value
.Range("G" & iRow) = TextBox7.Value
.Range("H" & iRow) = TextBox8.Value
.Range("I" & iRow) = TextBox9.Value
.Range("J" & iRow) = TextBox10.Value
.Range("K" & iRow) = TextBox11.Value
.Range("L" & iRow) = TextBox12.Value
.Range("M" & iRow) = TextBox13.Value
.Range("N" & iRow) = DTPicker1.Value
.Range("O" & iRow) = TextBox15.Value
.Range("P" & iRow) = TextBox16.Value
.Range("Q" & iRow) = TextBox17.Value
.Range("R" & iRow) = TextBox18.Value
.Range("S" & iRow) = TextBox20.Value
.Range("T" & iRow) = DTPicker3.Value
.Range("U" & iRow) = TextBox21.Value
.Range("V" & iRow) = TextBox22.Value
.Range("w" & iRow) = TextBox23.Value
.Range("X" & iRow) = DTPicker4.Value
.Range("Y" & iRow) = Application.UserName
.Range("Z" & iRow) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]
.Range("AA" & iRow) = TextBox24.Value
.Range("AB" & iRow) = cmbRD.Value
.Range("AC" & iRow) = newDate
.Range("AD" & iRow) = cmbDD.Value
End With
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Inventory Record PDF")
With ws1
.Range("C6").Value = TextBox1.Value
.Range("C7").Value = TextBox2.Value
.Range("C8").Value = TextBox3.Value
.Range("C9").Value = ComboBox2.Value
.Range("C10").Value = ComboBox3.Value
.Range("C11").Value = TextBox6.Value
.Range("C12").Value = TextBox13.Value
.Range("G6").Value = TextBox7.Value
.Range("G7").Value = TextBox8.Value
.Range("G8").Value = TextBox9.Value
.Range("G9").Value = TextBox10.Value
.Range("G10").Value = TextBox11.Value
.Range("G11").Value = TextBox12.Value
.Range("G13").Value = DTPicker1.Value
.Range("A15").Value = TextBox15.Value
.Range("B15").Value = TextBox16.Value
.Range("C15").Value = TextBox17.Value
.Range("D15").Value = TextBox18.Value
.Range("E15").Value = TextBox20.Value
.Range("F15").Value = DTPicker3.Value
End With
MsgBox "Saved Successfully"
'ws.Protect "Ramu@lt12", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox7_AfterUpdate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sh = Worksheets("Inventory Record")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("G:G"), frm1.TextBox7.Value) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'x = frm3.TextBox1.Value
    'Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(ReturnValueRange,Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH(LookUpValue, LookupRange, 0))
    On Error Resume Next
    With frm1
    
        .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .TextBox3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("C:C"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .ComboBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("D:D"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .ComboBox3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("E:E"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .TextBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("F:F"), WorksheetFunction.Match(frm1.TextBox7, sh.Range("G:G"), 0))
        .TextBox8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 2, 0)
        .TextBox9 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 3, 0)
        .TextBox10 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 4, 0)
        .TextBox11 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 5, 0)
        .TextBox12 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 6, 0)
        .TextBox13 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 7, 0)
        .DTPicker1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 8, 0)
        .TextBox15 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 9, 0)
        .TextBox16 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 10, 0)
        .TextBox17 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 11, 0)
        .TextBox18 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 12, 0)
        .TextBox20 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 13, 0)
        .DTPicker3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 14, 0)
        .TextBox21 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 15, 0)
        .TextBox22 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 16, 0)
        .TextBox23 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 17, 0)
        .DTPicker4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 18, 0)
        .TextBox24 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 21, 0)
        .cmbRD = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 22, 0)
        .cmbDD = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm1.TextBox7.Value, sh.Range("G:AD"), 24, 0)
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call Reset1
With frm1
 .DTPicker1.Value = Date
 .DTPicker3.Value = Date
 .DTPicker4.Value = Date
End With
End Sub
```

Another error in another form:
[image]

Full code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Transport Assesment")
ws.Protect Password:="Ramu@lt12", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

'find first row in database
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
.Range("A" & iRow) = TextBox1.Value
.Range("B" & iRow) = TextBox13.Value
.Range("C" & iRow) = DTPicker2.Value
.Range("D" & iRow) = ComboBox7.Value
.Range("E" & iRow) = ComboBox8.Value
.Range("F" & iRow) = ComboBox6.Value
.Range("G" & iRow) = ComboBox1.Value
.Range("H" & iRow) = TextBox2.Value
.Range("I" & iRow) = ComboBox2.Value
.Range("J" & iRow) = TextBox3.Value
.Range("K" & iRow) = ComboBox3.Value
.Range("L" & iRow) = TextBox4.Value
.Range("M" & iRow) = ComboBox4.Value
.Range("N" & iRow) = TextBox5.Value
.Range("O" & iRow) = ComboBox5.Value
.Range("P" & iRow) = TextBox6.Value
.Range("Q" & iRow) = DTPicker3.Value
.Range("R" & iRow) = TextBox14.Value
.Range("S" & iRow) = DTPicker4.Value
.Range("T" & iRow) = TextBox9.Value
.Range("U" & iRow) = DTPicker1.Value
.Range("X" & iRow) = Application.UserName
.Range("Y" & iRow) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]
.Range("Z" & iRow) = TextBox15.Value
.Range("AA" & iRow) = TextBox16.Value
End With
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Transport Assesment PDF")
With ws1
.Range("D8").Value = TextBox1.Value
.Range("D12").Value = TextBox13.Value
.Range("I12").Value = DTPicker2.Value
.Range("D14").Value = ComboBox8.Value
.Range("I14").Value = ComboBox7.Value
.Range("D20").Value = ComboBox6.Value
.Range("D22").Value = ComboBox1.Value
.Range("F23").Value = TextBox2.Value
.Range("D24").Value = ComboBox2.Value
.Range("F26").Value = TextBox3.Value
.Range("D27").Value = ComboBox3.Value
.Range("F28").Value = TextBox4.Value
.Range("D29").Value = ComboBox5.Value
.Range("H30").Value = TextBox5.Value
.Range("G34").Value = TextBox6.Value
.Range("G36").Value = DTPicker3.Value
.Range("I36").Value = TextBox14.Value
.Range("G39").Value = DTPicker4.Value
.Range("E49").Value = TextBox9.Value
.Range("I49").Value = DTPicker1.Value
.Range("J8").Value = DTPicker1.Value
.Range("D20").Value = TextBox15.Value
End With

MsgBox "Saved Successfully"
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Long
Dim ol As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Transport Assesment")
x = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
Dim fpath As String
   'Get file path
    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select Invoice to attach")
    If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
    
Dim fname As String
Dim fAddress As String
Dim finalpath As String
fname = GetFilenameFromPath(fpath)
Dim checklist As String
checklist = Left(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 4) & "-" & Right(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 2)
MkDir (checklist)

fAddress = "G:\BusUnits\PH\Sample management\"
finalpath = fAddress & checklist & "\" & fname
FileCopy fpath, finalpath
     
ws.Unprotect Password:="Ramu@lt12"
 
Dim id As Range
Set id = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=frm3.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If id Is Nothing Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("V" & iRow), _
            Address:=finalpath, _
            ScreenTip:="file address", _
            TextToDisplay:="Invoice " & frm3.TextBox1.Value
            ws.Range("V" & iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            
Else
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=id.Offset(, 21), _
            Address:=finalpath, _
            ScreenTip:="file address", _
            TextToDisplay:="Invoice " & frm3.TextBox1.Value
            id.Offset(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If

Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call Reset3
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Transport Assesment PDF").Activate
Dim checklist As String
Dim filename As String
Dim fullfilename As String

checklist = Left(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 4) & "-" & Right(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 2)
MkDir (checklist)
filename = "Transport Assesment" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".pdf"
fullfilename = "G:\BusUnits\PH\Sample management\" & checklist & "\" & filename


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=fullfilename, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Long
Dim ol As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Transport Assesment")
x = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Dim iRow As Long
iRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
Dim fpath As String
   'Get file path
    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select Invoice to attach")
    If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
    
Dim fname As String
Dim fAddress As String
Dim finalpath As String
fname = GetFilenameFromPath(fpath)
Dim checklist As String
checklist = Left(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 4) & "-" & Right(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 2)
MkDir (checklist)

fAddress = "G:\BusUnits\PH\Sample management\"
finalpath = fAddress & checklist & "\" & fname
FileCopy fpath, finalpath
     
ws.Unprotect Password:="Ramu@lt12"
 
 
Dim id As Range
Set id = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=frm3.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If id Is Nothing Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("W" & iRow), _
            Address:=finalpath, _
            ScreenTip:="file address", _
            TextToDisplay:="Datalogger " & frm3.TextBox1.Value
            ws.Range("W" & iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            
Else
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=id.Offset(, 22), _
            Address:=finalpath, _
            ScreenTip:="file address", _
            TextToDisplay:="Datalogger " & frm3.TextBox1.Value
            id.Offset(, 22).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If

Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate


End Sub

Private Sub Image1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Transport Assesment PDF").Activate
Dim checklist As String
Dim filename As String
Dim fullfilename As String

checklist = Left(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 4) & "-" & Right(frm3.TextBox1.Value, 2)
MkDir (checklist)
filename = "Transport Assesment" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".pdf"
fullfilename = "G:\BusUnits\PH\Sample management\" & checklist & "\" & filename


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=fullfilename, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1

End Sub

Private Sub imgEdit_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to Edit the Entry?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    frm6.Show

End Sub

Private Sub imgReset_Click()

    Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to reset the Form?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Call Reset3

End Sub

Private Sub imgSave_Click()
Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to save the Data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
    
    If msgValue = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Call Save3
    
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sh = Worksheets("Transport Assesment")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), frm3.TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'x = frm3.TextBox1.Value
    On Error Resume Next
    With frm3
    
        .TextBox13 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 2, 0)
        .DTPicker2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 3, 0) 'Invoice date
        .ComboBox7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 5, 0) 'Storage condition
        .ComboBox8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 4, 0)
        .ComboBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 6, 0)
        .TextBox15 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 26, 0)
        .ComboBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 7, 0)
        .TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 8, 0)
        .ComboBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 9, 0)
        .TextBox3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 10, 0)
        .ComboBox3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 11, 0)
        .TextBox4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 12, 0)
        .ComboBox4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 13, 0)
        .TextBox5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 14, 0)
        .ComboBox5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 15, 0)
        .TextBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 16, 0)
        .DTPicker3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 17, 0)
        .TextBox14 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 18, 0)
        .DTPicker4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 19, 0)
        .TextBox9 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 20, 0)
        .DTPicker1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 21, 0)
        .TextBox16 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(frm3.TextBox1, sh.Range("A:AA"), 27, 0)
        
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With frm3
        .TextBox1.Value = ""
        .TextBox2.Value = ""
        .TextBox3.Value = ""
        .TextBox4.Value = ""
        .TextBox5.Value = ""
        .TextBox6.Value = ""
        .TextBox9.Value = ""
        .TextBox13.Value = ""
        .TextBox14.Value = ""
        .TextBox15.Value = ""
        .TextBox16.Value = ""
        
        .DTPicker1.Value = Date
        .DTPicker2.Value = Date
        .DTPicker3.Value = Date
        .DTPicker4.Value = Date
        
        .ComboBox1.Clear
        .ComboBox2.Clear
        .ComboBox3.Clear
        .ComboBox4.Clear
        .ComboBox5.Clear
        .ComboBox6.Clear
        .ComboBox7.Clear
        .ComboBox8.Clear
        
        End With

With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Wooden Pack"
        .AddItem "Carton"
        .AddItem "Credo Box"
        .AddItem "Other"
 End With
 
 With ComboBox3
        .AddItem "Damaged"
        .AddItem "Intact"
        .AddItem "Opened"
        .AddItem "Other"
 End With
 
 With ComboBox2
        .AddItem "Damaged"
        .AddItem "Intact"
        .AddItem "Opened"
        .AddItem "Other"
 End With
 
 With ComboBox4
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
 End With
 
 With ComboBox5
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
 End With
 
 With ComboBox7
       .AddItem "Store below -15 C.(fridge)-(CODE -DEEP FREEZE)"
       .AddItem "Store in 2- 8 C.(Refrigerator)-( CODE-FRIGO)"
       .AddItem "Do not store above  25 C protect from moisture-(TEMPCONTROL)"
       .AddItem "Do not store above  25 C protect from light-(TEMPCONTROL )"
       .AddItem "Ambient moderate condition-(AMBIENT MODERATE)"
 End With
  With ComboBox6
       .AddItem "Switzerland (Basel)"
       .AddItem "China"
       .AddItem "Ringaskiddy (Ireland)"
       .AddItem "Germany"
       .AddItem "Italy"
       .AddItem "Japan"
       .AddItem "Slovenia"
       .AddItem " U.K (United Kingdom)"
       .AddItem "Deutschland"
       .AddItem "Others"
 End With
 With ComboBox8
       .AddItem "DEEP FREEZE"
       .AddItem "FRIGO"
       .AddItem "TEMPCONTROL"
       .AddItem "AMBIENT MODERATE"
       .AddItem "COLD"
 End With
 
 With cmbMaterial
 
    .AddItem "Reference Standard"
    .AddItem "Impurity"
    .AddItem "In-process samples"
    .AddItem "Packaging Materials"
 
 End With
 
With cmbQty

    .AddItem "All Samples"
    .AddItem "Others"

End With

 
End Sub
```

The other 2 form's Initialize is working fine as it was before, I don't know what happened to these two.
Also, whenever I try to remove the whole Initialize statement, it says it will reset the project, and when I click yes, excel just crashes.

Please help

Edit:
After putting break-point and running the first one:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is this form? Put a break point on `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` in all 3 forms and then run it?

Comment: The error changed to the expected end sub after putting break point, I have added a picture

Comment: And both the errors, yellow arrow are actually just above the userform_initialize sub. not on the sub

Comment: That looks like a different form. Now do the same thing with `Call Reset1` and press F8 when it is highlighted. you will have to step through the code to find the error

Comment: Whereever the yellow like is from there start pressing F8 and go to the faulty line

Comment: I just added 1 more End sub, above the initialize end sub, and it has started working

Comment: good. As an added measure, compile your project once.

Comment: It compiled successfully, but I am still not sure, why it is needing 2 End subs for 1 initialize statement. I hope it doesn't give me problems later on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222057/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-raghav-chamadiya).